# Why clearInterval() is not working in timer Js?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I am training to work with `js` and one of the projects was a pomodoro timer.
The timer works well from the main panel and stops and switches between tabs.
But if you click on the clock button in the header and select any of the options there, then the timer does not stop and is not cleared when switching tabs, and plus when it ends, it goes into minus.

```
timerInt = setInterval(timerF, 1000);
  function timerF() {
    if (sec === 0) {
      sec = 59;
      min--;
    } else {
      sec--;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
      timeSec.textContent = `0${sec}`;
    } else {
      timeSec.textContent = `${sec}`;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
      timeMin.textContent = `0${min}`;
    } else {
      timeMin.textContent = `${min}`;
    }
    if (sec <= 0 && min <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInt);
      timeSec.textContent = `00`;
      timeMin.textContent = `00`;
    }
  }
```

Here is the code that is executed when the first option is selected (20 min):

```
time1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  clearInterval(timerInt);
  timeChoose = 20;
  setTimes.classList.remove("active-time");
  startBtn.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  pomo.classList.add("active");
  longBreak.classList.remove("active");
  shortBreak.classList.remove("active");
  startBtn.classList.add("active-btn");
  timeSec.textContent = `00`;
  timeMin.textContent = `20`;
  startBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    timer(timeChoose);
    startBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  });
});
```

Link to an example page to make it easier to understand what I'm talking about and see the code.
Please help me to make the timer work well after selection
https://createchaoslab.github.io/pomo/

Comment: I check for seconds and minutes, if seconds and minutes are zero then the timer stops. i tried  `===` this option works but not after selecting in tabs

Comment: Yes, but it works together with minutes and if minutes and seconds are equal to zero then the interval stops

Comment: @RobinZigmond But sec could be `0`. Look `sec=1` and else statement works (`else {
      sec--;
    }`) and now `sec` is `0`. Then this (`f (sec <= 0 && min <= 0) `) statement works and it will `clearInterval`

Comment: @n-ata oops, you're right. Apologies to the OP, I'll remove my comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calss `Timer`. But there is no timer function.
Try this.

**EDITED:**

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const timeMin = document.querySelector(".time-min");
const timeSec = document.querySelector(".time-sec");
var startBtn = document.querySelector(".start-btn");
const time1 = document.querySelector(".time1");
const time2 = document.querySelector(".time2");
const time3 = document.querySelector(".time3");
const setTimes = document.querySelector(".set-times");
const setTimesBtn = document.querySelector(".set-time img");
let timerInt;
let timeChoose=2;

function timer(timeChoose = 10) {
  let sec = 0;
  let min = timeChoose;
  timerInt = setInterval(timerF, 1000);
  function timerF() {
    if (sec == 0) {
      sec = 59;
      min--;
    } else {
      sec--;
    }

    if (sec < 10) {
      timeSec.innerHTML = `0${sec}`;
    } else {
      timeSec.innerHTML = `${sec}`;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
      timeMin.innerHTML = `0${min}`;
    } else {
      timeMin.innerHTML = `${min}`;
    }
    if (sec <= 0 && min <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInt);
      timeSec.innerHTML = `00`;
      timeMin.innerHTML = `00`;
    }
  }
}



tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
      clearInterval(timerInt);
    [].forEach.call(tabs, function(el) {
            el.classList.remove("active");
    });

    this.classList.add("active");
    if(this.classList.contains('first')){
      timeSec.innerHTML = `00`;
          if (timeChoose < 10) {
                timeMin.innerHTML = `0${timeChoose}`;
              } else {
                timeMin.innerHTML = `${timeChoose}`;
              }
            startBtn.classList.add("active-btn");
      startBtn.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else{
        if(this.classList.contains('second')){
          timeSec.innerHTML = `00`;
          timeMin.innerHTML = `01`;
          timer(1);
        }
        else{
          timeSec.innerHTML = `00`;
          timeMin.innerHTML = `04`;   
          timer(4);
        }
                startBtn.classList.remove("active-btn");
    }
  });
});

function setT(min) {
  clearInterval(timerInt);

  timeChoose = min;
    [].forEach.call(tabs, function(el) {
            el.classList.remove("active");
    });
    setTimes.classList.remove("active-time");
  startBtn.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      first.classList.add("active");
  startBtn.classList.add("active-btn");
  timeSec.innerHTML = `00`;
  timeMin.innerHTML = `${timeChoose}`;
}

time1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    setT(20);
});
 
time2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    setT(40);
});
time3.addEventListener("click", function () {
    setT(60);
});


startBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  timer(timeChoose);
  startBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});
setTimesBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  setTimes.classList.toggle("active-time");
});
```

```css
body{
  background: rgb(221, 99, 0);
}

.header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.header-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.set-time {
    display: flex;

}

.set-time img {
    margin-left: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.set-times {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.set-times>* {
    display: none;
}

.set-times.active-time>* {
    display: block;
}

.set-times.active-time {
    visibility: visible;
    background: #ff8100;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all.4s;
    -moz-transition: all.4s;
    -ms-transition: all.4s;
    -o-transition: all.4s;
}

.time-var {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.time-var:hover {
    background-color: #f5812e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;

}

.time-var+.time-var {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.tabs{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  transition: all .3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
.tab.active{
  background:rgb(168, 60, 18);
}
#text {
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.start-btn.active-btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 230, 210);
    color: rgb(221, 99, 0);
    font-size: 15px;
    border: transparent;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
}
.start-btn {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header-inner">
          <div class="set-time">
                        <div class="set-times">
                            <div class="time-var time1">20 min</div>
                            <div class="time-var time2">40 min</div>
                            <div class="time-var time3">60 min</div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" />
                        
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab first active">
tab1
</div>
<div class="tab second">
tab2
</div>
<div class="tab third">
tab3
</div>
</div>
<div>


<div id="text">
<div class="time-min">02</div> :
<div class="time-sec">00</div>
</div>
<button class="start-btn active-btn">START</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve my problem. I changed the code to the one you did and my original problem was not solved. everything is the same when choosing minutes in the menu above and if you start the timer by pressing the start button, and then switch to long break or short break, the timer does not stop, but continues counting(

Comment: @wch Could you show me full code. Maybe in jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wphppp/yu7adjfn/7/ or https://createchaoslab.github.io/pomo/

Comment: just remove  `startBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {timer(timeChoose); startBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");});` from `time1.click()`, `time2.click` and `time3.click`

Comment: @wch look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/natacode/7m61pxuo/5/)

Comment: @wch now your code works. I edited your code.